# Install Chocolatey package if software is not installed, but skip install if newer version of software is already installed?

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy, chocolatey

I'm using the following PowerShell script to install dotnetcore-windowshosting version 1.1.1 via an Octopus Deploy step.

ChocolateyPackageId is equal to "dotnetcore-windowshosting" and
$ChocolateyPackageVersion is equal to "1.1.1".

However, the target machine has a new version of DotNetCore.1.0.4_1.1.1-WindowsHosting.exe installed than the version being installed by the Chocolatey package. As a result, an error is raised alerting me that the target machine already has a newer version installed.

How can I install the package using `cinst` like in the script, however, ignore and don't raise an error if the package being installed (or a newer version) is already installed?

```
$chocolateyBin = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", "Machine") + "\bin"
if(-not (Test-Path $chocolateyBin)) {
    Write-Output "Environment variable 'ChocolateyInstall' was not found in the system variables. Attempting to find it in the user variables..."
    $chocolateyBin = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", "User") + "\bin"
}

$cinst = "$chocolateyBin\cinst.exe"
$choco = "$chocolateyBin\choco.exe"

if (-not (Test-Path $cinst) -or -not (Test-Path $choco)) {
    throw "Chocolatey was not found at $chocolateyBin."
}

if (-not $ChocolateyPackageId) {
    throw "Please specify the ID of an application package to install."
}

$chocoVersion = & $choco --version
Write-Output "Running Chocolatey version $chocoVersion"

$chocoArgs = @()
if([System.Version]::Parse($chocoVersion) -ge
   [System.Version]::Parse("0.9.8.33")) {
    Write-Output "Adding --confirm to arguments passed to Chocolatey"
    $chocoArgs += @("-y", "")
}

if (-not $ChocolateyPackageVersion) {
    Write-Output "Installing package $ChocolateyPackageId from the Chocolatey package repository..."
    & $cinst $ChocolateyPackageId $($chocoArgs)
}
else {
    Write-Output "Installing package $ChocolateyPackageId version $ChocolateyPackageVersion from the Chocolatey package repository..." & $cinst $ChocolateyPackageId -Version $ChocolateyPackageVersion $($chocoArgs)
}
```

Comment: Was the newer version of the application installed via Chocolatey, or was it installed manually?

Comment: Hey... although I would like to enforce that the application is always installed via Chocolatey, in the real world this just isn't possible. So yes it could have been installed manually.

Comment: When you say that there is an error during the installation, can you confirm exactly what you mean by this?  For example, if it is returning with a standard error code, it could be that the Chocolatey Package itself needs to be updated to include that as a valid exit code.

Comment: I get the following output from powershell...

Failures
 - dotnetcore-windowshosting (exited 1638) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\dotnetcore-windowshostin
g\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

And the Error Log contains the following...

[2014:2618][2017-11-28T22:58:09]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[2014:3CF0][2017-11-28T22:58:09]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed.
[2014:2618][2017-11-28T22:58:09]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x666

Comment: It would be interesting to see the complete log, also, if you run the choco install command passing in -dv you will get more complete information.  Ideally, we would get the exit code from the installation attempt, and push that back into the validExitCodes for the package.

Comment: Hey Gary do you have an email address I could send the log files to? I would really appreciate your feedback. I added the exit code which I'm getting which is 1638 to the validExitCodes but the error still surfaces as an error (red text) in powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. Below seems to work for me

```
$chocolateyBin = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", "Machine") + "\bin"
if(-not (Test-Path $chocolateyBin)) {
    Write-Output "Environment variable 'ChocolateyInstall' was not found in the system variables. Attempting to find it in the user variables..."
    $chocolateyBin = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ChocolateyInstall", "User") + "\bin"
}

$cinst = "$chocolateyBin\cinst.exe"
$choco = "$chocolateyBin\choco.exe"

if (-not (Test-Path $cinst) -or -not (Test-Path $choco)) {
    throw "Chocolatey was not found at $chocolateyBin."
}

if (-not $ChocolateyPackageId) {
    throw "Please specify the ID of an application package to install."
}

$chocoVersion = & $choco --version
Write-Output "Running Chocolatey version $chocoVersion"

$chocoArgs = @()
if([System.Version]::Parse($chocoVersion) -ge [System.Version]::Parse("0.9.8.33")) {
    Write-Output "Adding --confirm to arguments passed to Chocolatey"
    $chocoArgs += @("-y", "")
}

if (-not $ChocolateyPackageVersion) {
    Write-Output "Installing package $ChocolateyPackageId from the Chocolatey package repository..."
    & $cinst $ChocolateyPackageId $($chocoArgs)
} else {
    Write-Output "Installing package $ChocolateyPackageId version $ChocolateyPackageVersion from the Chocolatey package repository..."
    & $cinst $ChocolateyPackageId -Version $ChocolateyPackageVersion $($chocoArgs) --force
}

$codes = $IgnoreExitCodes -split ','

if ($codes -Contains $lastExitCode)
{
    exit 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Open Source

Continue on with the script you are working on, however check the exit code of what you are installing, it may have a valid exit code that specifies a newer version is already installed.

#### Commercial

Probably the best way to achieve what you are looking for already exists. Chocolatey for Business has the sync command and automatic sync. https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-synchronize

If you ran `choco sync` and then called your install, you would already have a newer version of that package being managed by Chocolatey. Thus it would ignore your script.

```
choco sync
choco upgrade <name> -y <options>
```

Upgrade here achieves install if the package is not installed and upgraded if there is a newer version in your sources

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is hacky. And not in a good way.

```
function Test-ChocolateyPackageInstalled {
    Param (
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $Package
    )

    Process {
        if (Test-Path -Path $env:ChocolateyInstall) {
            $packageInstalled = Test-Path -Path $env:ChocolateyInstall\lib\$Package
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Can't find a chocolatey install directory..."
        }

        return $packageInstalled
    }
}

$package = "dotnetcore-windowshosting"


if (Test-ChocolateyPackageInstalled -Package $package) {
    Write-Warning "Package is already installed"
}
else {
    choco install $package -confirm
}
```

I've only ever installed this via Chocolatey, so I will have a hard time testing your scenario when someone else has installed manually, but the methodology might have legs.

Therefore also note that this may not solve your problem completely; but it could help future readers.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same as what the OP was talking about - I clarified the title, you may wish to edit your answer.