# Powershell script for software automation

Tags: powershell, automation, menu, display, user-interaction

```
function show-menu
{

      Clear-Host
      write-host "**********************************************"
      write-host "LIST OF SOFTWARES"

      write-host " 1. googlechrome"
      write-host " 2. firebox"

      write-host " 3. CodeBlocks"
      write-host " 4. windbg"

      
      write-host " 5. nasm"
      write-host " 6. explorer suite"
      

      write-host " 7.pestudio"
      write-host " 8.vscode"

      write-host " 9. sysinternals"
      write-host " 10. python"

      write-host " q. Exit the script"
      write-host " ************************************************"

 }


do
{
   show-menu

      $UserInput = read-host "Enter the software number to be installed "

           switch($UserInput)
           {

                1 {googlechrome;
                   
                    pause
                   }

                2 {firefox;pause}

                3 {codeblocks;pause}
                4 {windbg;pause}

                
                5 {nasm;pause}
                6 {explorersuite;pause}
               

                7 {pestudio;pause}
                8 {vscode;pause}

                9{sysinternals;pause}
                10{python;pause}

                q {break}

                default {write-host "Error in selection, choose 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 or q";pause}
            }
}

while ($UserInput -ne 'q')

$Packages = 'googlechrome',
            'firefox',
            'codeblocks',
            'windbg',
            'nasm',
            'explorersuite',
            'pestudio',
            'vscode',
            'sysinternals',
            'python'

If(Test-Path -Path "$env:ProgramData\Chocolatey")
{

      ### Installing Packagers

     ForEach($PackageName in $Packages)
     {
        choco install $PackageName -y
     }

}


    Else
    {
      

       Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]:: SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

       ###### package install stuff ###############

       ForEach($PackageName in $Packages)
       {
            Choco install $PackageName -Y
       }

    }
```

The script is not working properly. when i enter any number the software is not downloading but when i quit the software is downloding if anything is wrong in my script please tell me how to do it and in my system already some of the softwares are already installed but the script is downloading that software but during installing the script is giving message that the software is already installed. I need to put some condition in my script that if the software is already installed in the pc the script should not download the software it simply should give message like the software is already installed.
please help me in accomplishing my task
Thanking you

Thanking you

---

```
    enter code here

   do
{
        show-menu

        $Packages = 'googlechrome','firefox','codeblocks', 'windbg','nasm','explorersuite','pestudio','vscode','sysinternals','python'
        $UserInput = read-host "Enter the software number to be installed "

      
         switch($UserInput)
         {

             case1: {googlechrome;pause}

                    If(Test-Path -Path "$env:ProgramData\Chocolatey")
                     {

                                ### Installing Packagers

                            ForEach($PackageName in $Packages)
                            {
                                    choco install $PackageName -y
                             }

                        }


    
                    Else
                    {
                          ############### INSTALLING CHOCOLATEY ####################################################################################
                         ########### Before Executing the script type the command in the powershell terminal to get the admin rights ##############
                         ##########   Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ##################################################

                        Set-ExexutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]:: SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

                         ###### package install stuff ###############

                          ForEach($PackageName in $Packages)
                          {
                              choco install $PackageName -Y
                          }

                      }



               case2: {firefox;pause}


                If(Test-Path -Path "$env:ProgramData\Chocolatey")
                {

                        ### Installing Packagers

                     ForEach($PackageName in $Packages)
                     {
                        choco install $PackageName -y
                     }

                 }

Sir is it correct way iam getting missing statement block in switch statement clause
```

Comment: This question keeps being asked.. Are you perhaps the same person as [jhansi jatavath](jhansi jatavath) or are you in the same classroom? As I have commented in one of the earlier question, where is the logic in your code? You show a menu, do **nothing** with the chosen option and afterwards install everything that is in some variable `$Packages`..

Comment: sir actually we are working together. may be she would have asked sir we are  new for power-shell script we are not getting any idea of how to put logic in that script so kindly help sir it would be helpful for us.

Comment: It really isn't that hard, just think about it some more: You are now running the `Show-Menu` function inside a loop, but only exit that when someone enters `q`. For all other options **nothing** gets done. Only when the user exits that loop with `q` (for QUIT) installation takes place **regardless** of what the user wanted to have installed. My tip: Inside the loop, where you test what the user entered, install that chosen package right there and then. Remove everything you have after `while ($UserInput -ne 'q')`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I would change the script to do this:

```
# Step 1) install Chocolatey when needed
if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$env:ProgramData\Chocolatey\choco.exe" -PathType Leaf)) {
   # from https://chocolatey.org/install
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072
   Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) 
}

# Step 2) define the array of packages you are offering
$Packages = 'googlechrome','firefox','codeblocks','windbg','nasm',
            'explorersuite','pestudio','vscode','sysinternals','python'

# Step 3) define the Show-Menu function
function Show-Menu {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "**********************************************"
    Write-Host "LIST OF SOFTWARES"
    # write the options using the array of packages
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Packages.Count; $i++) {
        # {0,2} means right align with spaces to max 2 characters
        Write-Host ('{0,2}. {1}' -f ($i + 1), $Packages[$i])
    }
    Write-Host " q. Exit the script"
    Write-Host "*************************************************"
    Write-Host
}

# Step 4) enter an endless loop you only exit if the user enters 'q'
while ($true) {
    Show-Menu

    $UserInput = Read-Host "Enter the software number to be installed"
    # test if the user wants to quit and if so, break the loop
    if ($UserInput -eq 'q') { break }

    # test if the user entered a number between 1 and the total number of packages (inclusive)
    if ([int]::TryParse($UserInput,[ref]$null) -and 1..$Packages.Count -contains [int]$UserInput) {
        # here you install the chosen package using the array index number (= user input number minus 1)
        $packageIndex = [int]$UserInput - 1
        Write-Host "Installing $($Packages[$packageIndex])"
        choco install $Packages[$packageIndex] -y
    }
    else {
        $availableOptions = 1..$Packages.Count -join ','
        Write-Host "Error in selection, choose $availableOptions or q" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    $null = Read-Host "Press Enter to continue"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, Sir when i run the script the software installation going into program data not in program files and also if the software is already installed then also software is downloding .

Comment: @ShravanMeghavath Possibly, but that has nothing to do with PowerShell. You can use many options and install switches to how and where Chocolatey installs the software. The best thing to do I think is to create a [Packages.config file](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#packages.config) XML file, so choco knows what to do for each mentioned software. You need to study how choko works in that regard. They even offer a video [here](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/chocolatey-gui/commands/config)

Comment: Sir, i have to complete this script as part my assignment and deadline is 2nd September please help me sir, 1.the script when i running exec files not showing in control panel and desktop icon is also not creating. 2. If the software is already installed then also software is downloading 3. If any upgrade is their for any software then the upgrade has to be taken place. kindly help me sir .

Comment: @ShravanMeghavath Sorry, but I don't use Chocolately and looking through the [commandline switches](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#options-and-switches), I don't see anything that can first check if a package is installed or not.. Depending on your version, Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543832/9898643) can help you there..

Comment: @Theo I believe gracefully "importing" software that has already been installed to be managed by Chocolatey is a feature of Chocolatey Pro. As I don't use Chocolatey Pro myself I can't speak to how that works. In my own packages I check for the presence of the MSI ProductCode (for msi installers) and skip running the installer if installed as a sort of "poor man's Chocolatey Pro" but that only works for packages which contain such a mechanism.